# Website - Remove/dont show option "save image as" and "open/copy image"

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I am development a new website (html + css + javascript) and I want disable the open "save image as" and "open/copy image" in browser (in desktop and smartphone).

My images code:

```
<a href="images/collection/photo1.jpg" class="photography-entry img image-popup d-flex justify-content-start align-items-end" style="background-image: url(images/collection/photo1.jpg);">
```

It is possible with this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable 'save image as' option on right click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020321/how-to-disable-save-image-as-option-on-right-click)

Comment: @ZenMonkey but that solution its possible with my code? I try but nothing workds :(

Comment: Edit: Now works! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score -3):

Well on browser, you can try `javascript - oncontextmenu="return false"`.